# Offset() не возвращает координаты элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь достать координаты из только что динамически созданного элемента. Самый нижний метод. Консоли выдают 0. Если вывести в консолье весь `this`, то видно что и лево, право, низ и верх в оффсете есть. Подскажите причину нулей? При этом метод `width()` на пример, прекрасно срабатывает.

```
           $(this)
                .append($('<div>')
                    .addClass('sossage drop')
                    .css({
                        'background-color': plColor,
                        'width': plLength + 'px',
                        'left': (plPosition - $('.playlists').offset().left) - cursorShift
                    })
                    .attr({
                        'id': identifier,
                        'name': plName
                    })
                    .dblclick(function () {
                        var popupPositionY = parseInt($(this).css('top')) - 230  /*popup height + 8px above*/;
                        var popupPositionX = (parseInt($(this).css('left')) - 76 /*middle of popup width*/) + 
                            +(parseInt($(this).css('width')) / 2 /*half of playlist width*/);
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        plSausage = this;
                        $('.pl-popup')
                            .show()
                            .css({
                                'top': popupPositionY + 'px',
                                'left': popupPositionX + 'px'
                            });
                        $('.pl-popup .popup_header span')
                            .text('Playlist: ' + name);
                    })
                    .each(function () {
                        coordinateCollector($(this).attr('id'), $(this));
                        console.log($(this).offset());
                        console.log($(this).offset().top);
                    }));
```

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh только что созданный `$('<div>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас контекст в each не верный, this там ведет на вызываемую функцию итератор или элемент которого в DOM еще нет ...